# Creating postgres tablespace permission denied even though owned by postgres

Tags: linux, postgresql, database, fedora

I have been trying to create a tablespace in postgresql 9.5 and I have been consistently getting issues with permission denied. I have finally decided I'm going to create a directory in `/` just to see if I could get anything to work but with no luck so far.

For reference:

```
[root@server ~]# cd /
[root@server /]# mkdir test
[root@server /]# chown postgres:postgres test
[root@server /]# su postgres
bash-4.3$ psql
psql (9.5.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE test LOCATION '/test';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/test": Permission denied
postgres=# \q
bash-4.3$ cd test
bash-4.3$ chmod 777 .
bash-4.3$ ls -alh
total 8.0K
drwsrwsrwx.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K Jan 27 20:15 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root     root     4.0K Jan 27 20:15 ..
bash-4.3$ pwd -P
/test
bash-4.3$ psql
psql (9.5.5)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE TABLESPACE test LOCATION '/test';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/test": Permission denied
```

I've even given the directory 777 and it is quite obviously owned by postgres. At this point I'm not sure what to do to get this to work. I'm running fedora-25. I would ideally like to not put this in `/` and actually put it on a separate disk but I can't even get this basic case to work. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have SELinux enabled, and have missed that it is blocking this.

You can see the log entries in the audit log `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

The easiest way to resolve the problem is to use the default data directory location, `/var/lib/pgsql` and to not try to override it. Rather, mount your storage at this location.

Comment: EDIT: Is there a page you can direct me to that would be a good resource on figuring out how to properly have SELinux allow it this time?

Comment: @legion You will have to undo it later, and end up setting it up all over again in the way I've described. But knowing what's going on is a good idea, so I would suggest you read [Red Hat's SELinux documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/SELinux_Users_and_Administrators_Guide/index.html) which is about 99.9% applicable.

Comment: Fantastic thank you very much I'll take a look into it

Answer (score 1):

I was faced similar problem at Fedora. Even `/var/log/audit/audit.log` did not provided any clue the reason is SElinux.

Tablespace dir is ok.

```
[me@my /]$ ls -alr /psql
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres 4096 14.Mar 22.56 a
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root     root     4096 14.Mar 15.13 ..
drwxr-xr-x.  3 postgres postgres 4096 14.Mar 15.21 .
```

But CREATE TABLESPACE failed.

```
[me@my /]# psql -U postgres 
postgres=# create tablespace test_index location '/psql/a';
ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "/psql/a": Permission denied
postgres=# \quit
```

Stracing confirmed an issue:

```
[me@my /]$ ps ax |grep postgres
18719 ?        S      0:00 /usr/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/pgsql/data
18720 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: logger process
18722 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: checkpointer process
18723 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: writer process
18724 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: wal writer process
18725 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process
18726 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: stats collector process
20446 ?        Ss     0:00 postgres: postgres postgres [local] idle

strace failed:

[me@my /]$ sudo strace -p 20446
strace: Process 20446 attached
epoll_pwait(3, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=2672404064, u64=94302974355040}}], 1, -1, NULL, 8) = 1
recvfrom(11, "Q\0\0\0005create tablespace test_inde"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 54
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 8192
chmod("/psql/a", 0700)                  = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
```

**Switching off SElinux finally solved the problem**

```
[me@my /]# setenforce 0
[me@my /]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31
[me@my /]# psql -U postgres 
psql (9.6.7)

postgres=# create tablespace test_index location '/psql/a';
CREATE TABLESPACE
```

strace success:

```
epoll_pwait(3, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=3479758432, u64=94226472298080}}], 1, -1, NULL, 8) = 1
recvfrom(11, "Q\0\0\0005create tablespace test_inde"..., 8192, 0, NULL, NULL) = 54
lseek(5, 0, SEEK_END)                   = 8192
chmod("/psql/a", 0700)                  = 0
mkdir("/psql/a/PG_9.6_201608131", 0700) = 0
symlink("/psql/a", "pg_tblspc/16454")   = 0
```

Note: adding `postgres` user to `root` group did not help.